# Installation error with Octave on Homebrew OS X Mountain lion (10.8.5)

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, octave, homebrew, failed-installation

I am trying to install Octave on Mac 10.8.5 using Homebrew.

I ran the following commands in the terminal to install that after installing Xquartz.

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew update && brew upgrade
brew install octave
```

After doing this it successfully installed all the dependencies and finally reached at the last option of installing octave as shown below. But while installing Octave it gave the following error:

```
==> Installing octave
==> Using Homebrew-provided fortran compiler.
This may be changed by setting the FC environment variable.
==> Downloading http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/octave/octave-3.6.4.tar.bz2
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading patches
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Patching
patching file configure.ac
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1605 (offset 2 lines).
==> autoreconf -ivf
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/octave/3.6.4 --with-blas=-Wl,-framewo
==> make all
==> make install
./plot.texi:3957: warning: node `Multiple Plot Windows' is prev for `Printing and Saving Plots' in menu but not in sectioning
make[3]: *** [octave.info] Error 1
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install] Error 2

READ THIS: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
If reporting this issue please do so at (not mxcl/homebrew):
  https://github.com/homebrew/homebrew-science/issues
```

Kindly note that all the dependencies which gets installed when you run brew install octave didn't throw and error and after that only it started installing octave.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this link
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/444

use --enable-docs=no option. It will work on mountain lion.

I too had the same issue; fixed by adding the option.